# How to do type-safe indices in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, collections, type-safety, type-alias

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
typealias HumanId = Int 
typealias RobotId = Int

func getHuman(at index: HumanId) -> Human
func getRobot(at index: RobotId) -> Robot
```

but as it is now I can call `getHuman` with `RobotId` just fine: `getHuman(at: RobotId(0))`.

How do I make this typesafe?

---

I understand that I can do something like:

```
struct HumanId { let id: Int }
struct RobotId { let id: Int }
```

...and some extra things to make these structs function as indices, but that would lead to some code duplication, and since I'm having more than 2 of these id-types I would like to shorten this somehow, with typealiases and generics perhaps in order to make them unique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could leverage Swift *generics* to achieve your goal. Introduce a generic `Index` type like this:

```swift
struct Index<T>: RawRepresentable {
    let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }
    init(_ rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```swift
func getHuman(at index: Index<Human>) -> Human { ... }
func getRobot(at index: Index<Robot>) -> Robot { ... }

getHuman(at: Index(1))
getRobot(at: Index(2))
```

#### Literal Indices

You could even use the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` protocol to provide some syntax sugar when using *literal indices*:

```swift
extension Index: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) { self.rawValue = value }
}
```

For instance:

```swift
getHuman(at: 1)
getRobot(at: 2)
```

But the following code will *not* build, so the solution is still typesafe-ish:

```swift
let someIndex = 123
getHuman(at: someIndex)
```

> `error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Index<Human>'`

#### Comparable Indices

As suggested in the comments, we could also add `Comparable` conformance as well (e.g., so you can use the `Index` struct as the index in a type conforming to the standard `Collection` protocol):

```swift
extension Index: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Index, rhs: Index) -> Bool {
        lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}
```

Example:

```swift
Index<Human>(1) < Index<Human>(2) // true
```

Comment: I like the elegance of this answer. You should add `Comparable` conformance so you can use the type as the index in a type conforming to `Collection`